# Using one laravel core for multiple application

Tags: php, laravel

I am a programmer who familiar with Java and .NET.
Now for some personal project, I want to host it to my shared hosting using PHP. I just learn PHP, and I select Laravel because I saw it very look like Spring MVC and ASP.NET I used already.

But I have a concern is that, each project will **INCLUDE** the laravel framework folder (in /vendor). So if I have multiple laravel projects (create by composer), I will have multiple laravel framework core file for each project. This is a kind of duplicated resources, reduce my disk space a lot.

Are there any solution for that? Example use one laravel framework core for multiple project. I mean the folder /vendor/laravel. I used Java Spring and ASP.NET and for these framework, we can store libraries of framework (.jar or .dll) in a folder, then reference it from projects.

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend that. Since the vendor directory is based on the composer.json file. Each project has its own composer.json so the vendor directory should be generated according to the json file.

Comment: Yes, there might be inconsistencies between the different composer.jsons. I can't imagine saving 60-70mb being worth that trouble.

Comment: so why in java maven or nuget we can get that. for example I just need to download jar file of spring mvc and refer to huge numbers of project. I need one laravel package for all my php projects. could it possible?

Comment: any solution? or the PHP world people don't do that?